# Fabric can't find hidden function (starting with "_")

Tags: python, fabric

I want to run the command

`fab --fabfile=get_nb_samples_in_each_island.py _get_sample_names:'external_scripts/SICER/in/regular_no_blacklist_head.bed'`

This outputs the following:

```
Warning: Command(s) not found:
    _get_sample_names

Available commands:

    Counter                           Dict subclass for counting hashable items.  Sometimes called a bag
    INFO                              Log a message with severity 'INFO' on the root logger.
    defaultdict                       defaultdict(default_factory[, ...]) --> dict with default factory
    get_island_to_nb_samples_mapping  Finds out which samples are represented within each island. By sample we mean the experimental condition
    itemgetter                        itemgetter(item, ...) --> itemgetter object
    make_intervaltrees                Creates an intervaltree from an input file.
    natural_sort                      Sorts in the natural way for humans, not X1, X11, X12, but X1, X2, X3 ...
```

From this, it is obvious that fabric is not able to use hidden functions, i.e. those starting with underscore. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Couldn't you just alias the `_get_sample_names` function inside the file?  `get_sample_names = _get_sample_names` and `fab --fabfile=get_nb_samples_in_each_island.py get_sample_names:'external_scripts/SICER/in/regular_no_blacklist_head.bed'`

Comment: Or just change the function names themselves, but ideally I'd want to meddle as little as possible with the files. I'm just using `fabric` as a helper tool, I do not want the end product to be different because of it.

Comment: If you don't want to change the file, could you make another file that just does `from originalfile import _stuff; stuff = _stuff`?

Comment: Thanks both of you. I'm starting to guess this isn't possible then, will look at your alternatives.